# Can't exit function properly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, proyecto26.restclient

I have a C# unity function and I'm trying to request some json from a webserver but for some reason its not exiting the function where I want it to:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using Proyecto26;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using System.Text;
using TMPro;
using SimpleJSON;

public class APIRequest
{
   // string basicRequestPage = "****";
    string basicAPI_Key = "****";
    // Start is called before the first frame update

    string outputs;


    public string basicRequest(int requestTyp)
    {


        auth test1 = new auth();

        test1.key = basicAPI_Key;


        switch (requestTyp)
        {
            case 0:
                test1.request = "deckList";
                break;
            case 1:
                test1.request = "card";
                break;

        }
        string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test1);

        byte[] outputToServer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(output); ;


        //Debug.Log(output);

        RestClient.Request(new RequestHelper
        {
            Uri = basicRequestPage,
            Method = "POST",
            Timeout = 10,
            //EnableDebug = true,
            ParseResponseBody = false, //Don't encode and parse downloaded data as JSONe
            BodyRaw = outputToServer
        }).Then(response =>
        {
            // EditorUtility.DisplayDialog("Status", response.Text, "Ok");
            var rest = response.Text;
            //Debug.Log(rest);
            outputs = rest.ToString();
            //EditorUtility.DisplayDialog("Status", outputs, "Ok");
            return outputs;

        }).Catch(err =>
        {
            var error = err as RequestException;
            EditorUtility.DisplayDialog("Error Response", error.Response + "", "Ok");


        }


        );


    }
}
```

[Link to code because it wouldn't work with the built in code text](https://pastebin.com/BvJ5Rmmb)

It works perfectly fine as a method but keeps complaining that I don't have a valid return from the function. When I try to return the value I get from API, namely the outputs variable, it says it null. I have tried putting it in the function, in a public variable. but to now avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: In the `).Catch( err => ...` block , either throw an exception or `return "";` The function must return something in _any_ case. Not just the happy path.

Comment: Suggestion: add default case in your switch statement

Answer (score 0):

When you're working with promises you need to return a promise from that method too [(Promise chaining)](https://github.com/Real-Serious-Games/C-Sharp-Promise#chaining-async-operations):

```cs
public IPromise<string> basicRequest(int requestTyp)
{
    return RestClient.Request(new RequestHelper
    {
        Uri = basicRequestPage,
        Method = "POST",
        Timeout = 10,
        //EnableDebug = true,
        ParseResponseBody = false, //Don't encode and parse downloaded data as JSONe
        BodyRaw = outputToServer
    }).Then(response => response.Text.ToString());
}
```

For more details, check the repository of the Promises library used by the RestClient for Unity [here](https://github.com/Real-Serious-Games/C-Sharp-Promise#chaining-async-operations).

Comment: Thanks that worked for the most part, how can I convert that Ipromise into a string, it doesn;t seem to have any information in it. I've looked all through the documentation but I for the life of me can not figure it out.

Comment: But why? You can't convert async operations to synchronous, if you want to use IEnumerator instead, so check this example https://github.com/Real-Serious-Games/C-Sharp-Promise/issues/17#issuecomment-220521540

Comment: The "response.text.ToString" has Jason info I need and I can't seem to be able to access it by returning just the I promise<string>. I suppose I need to read up on async more. I have a work around currently but it's inconsistent.

Comment: Please create a new issue from the repository and attach your code/repository to understand better your scenario https://github.com/proyecto26/RestClient/issues

Comment: Will do after work, thanks

Answer (score -1):

You have defined an output of type `string` however you do not return a string at all exits. After the `catch` you have to return a string either at the end of the method or in the `catch`. The last line I have added  `return "";` should solve the problem.

```
public string basicRequest(int requestTyp)
{
    auth test1 = new auth();
    test1.key = basicAPI_Key;
    switch (requestTyp)
    {
        case 0:
            test1.request = "deckList";
            break;
        case 1:
            test1.request = "card";
            break;

    }
    string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test1);
    byte[] outputToServer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(output);

    //Debug.Log(output);

    RestClient.Request(new RequestHelper
    {
        Uri = basicRequestPage,
        Method = "POST",
        Timeout = 10,
        //EnableDebug = true,
        ParseResponseBody = false, //Don't encode and parse downloaded data as JSONe
        BodyRaw = outputToServer
    }).Then(response =>
    {
        // EditorUtility.DisplayDialog("Status", response.Text, "Ok");
        var rest = response.Text;
        //Debug.Log(rest);
        outputs = rest.ToString();
        //EditorUtility.DisplayDialog("Status", outputs, "Ok");
        return outputs;

    }).Catch(err =>
    {
        var error = err as RequestException;
        EditorUtility.DisplayDialog("Error Response", error.Response + "", "Ok");
    }
    );
    return ""; //<----- this here
}
```

Comment: Although I can see I'm getting a response with the DisplayDialog, when i add what you suggested, the only string i receive is "", it seems to bypass the return I put in earlier in the code.

Comment: adding to catch only still says "doesn't have valid return"

Comment: @danielrobbins you are telling in the method header that you return string. So all exit paths in the method has to define the return. I guess the compiler sees other exits paths, so adding the return "" at the end of the method as shown should resolve it.
The return at the end doesn't bypass the return you have entered, your return is never hit, as the method would return then, meaning that you never end up in the .Then part. Try and add a breakpoint there and debug, it will probably not get hit.

Comment: I added a break point and it did hit the return in the response function. I believe. For some reason it seems to execute the bottom return first, then the proper return, and thats why I'm getting a null value. Could it be because its not waiting for the response first?